# The 'right' way to run unit tests in Clojure

Tags: testing, clojure

Currently, I define the following function in the REPL at the start of a coding session:

```
(defn rt []
  (let [tns 'my.namespace-test]
    (use tns :reload-all)
    (cojure.test/test-ns tns)))
```

And everytime I make a change I rerun the tests:

```
user=>(rt)
```

That been working moderately well for me. When I remove a test, I have to restart the REPL and redefine the method which is a little annoying. Also I've heard bad rumblings about using the `use` function like this. So my questions are:

- Is using `use` this way going to cause me a problem down the line?
- Is there a more idiomatic workflow than what I'm currently doing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also run tests in my REPL. I like doing this because I have more control over the tests and it's faster due to the JVM already running. However, like you said, it's easy to get in trouble. In order to clean things up, I suggest taking a look at [tools.namespace](http://clojure.github.io/tools.namespace/).

In particular, you can use `clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh` to reload files that have changed in your live REPL. There's also`refresh-all` to reload all the files on the classpath.

I add tools.namespace to my `:dev` profile in my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` so that I have it there for every project. Then when you run `lein repl`, it will be included on the classpath, but it wont leak into your project's proper dependencies.

Another thing I'll do when I'm working on a test is to require it into my REPL and run it manually. A test is just a no-argument function, so you can invoke them as such.

Answer (score 18):

most people run

```
lein test
```

form a different terminal. Which guarantees that what is in the files is what is tested not what is in your memory. Using `reload-all` can lead to false passes if you have changed a function name and are still calling the old name somewhere.

- calling `use` like that is not a problem in it's self, it just constrains you to not have any name conflicts if you use more namespaces in your tests. So long as you have one, it's ok.
- using lein lets you specify unit and [integration tests](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md) and easily run them in groups using the test-selectors feature.

Comment: I started out running tests with `lein test` but the tests take so much longer to run when when compared to running them in the REPL. Is that expected or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: [clojure.test](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh), [expectations](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-autoexpect), speclj, and midje all support watching file changes and automatically run tests (which is fast except the first loading).If you're using emacs, [cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#upgrading-from-clojure-test-mode) has a clojure-test-mode which runs tests in emacs on top of repl, which is pretty cool

Answer (score 7):

I am so far impressed with [lein-midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Lein-midje)

`$ lein midje :autotest`

Starts a clojure process watching src and test files, reloads the associated namespaces and runs the tests relevant to the changed file (tracking dependencies). I use it with VimShell to open a split buffer in vim and have both the source and the test file open as well. I write a change to either one and the (relevant) tests are executed in the split pane.